# Convert JSON to parquet in Java

Tags: java, json, hadoop, avro, parquet

I am trying to convert JSON to parquet format in Java, but I am getting an exception.

Input JSON:

```
{"list": [ {"mainBearingX": 0.178334,
            "gearBoxZ": 0.03885,
            "_t": 1560305236290000,
            "mainBearingZ": 0.034438,
            "gearBoxX": 0.035738,
            "mainBearingY": 0.029445,
            "gearBoxY": 0.040929,
            "generatorX": 0.776837,
            "generatorY": 0.124234,
            "ts_id":"t1"
           },
           {"mainBearingX": 0.169478,
            "gearBoxZ": 0.008242,
            "_t": 1560305236311000,
            "mainBearingZ": 0.007531,
            "gearBoxX": 0.025647,
            "mainBearingY": 0.029445,
            "gearBoxY": 0.026282,
            "generatorX": 0.770189,
            "generatorY": 0.117464,
            "ts_id": "t1"
           }
         ]
}
```

The code:

```
public static void toConvert(OutPut output) {
            String inputFile = "test.parquetFile";
            Path dataFile = new Path(inputFile);
            Schema schema = ReflectData.AllowNull.get().getSchema(OutPut.class);
            try (ParquetWriter<OutPut> writer = AvroParquetWriter.<OutPut>builder(dataFile)
                    .withSchema(schema)
                    .withDataModel(ReflectData.get())
                    .withConf(new Configuration())
                    .withCompressionCodec(CompressionCodecName.SNAPPY)
                    .withWriteMode(Mode.OVERWRITE)
                    .build()) {
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
public class OutPut {
    List<Map<String, Object>> list;
}
```

The exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.parquet.schema.InvalidSchemaException: Cannot write a schema with an empty group: required group value {}
at org.apache.parquet.schema.TypeUtil$1.visit(TypeUtil.java:27)
at org.apache.parquet.schema.GroupType.accept(GroupType.java:226)
at org.apache.parquet.schema.TypeUtil$1.visit(TypeUtil.java:31)
at org.apache.parquet.schema.GroupType.accept(GroupType.java:226)
at org.apache.parquet.schema.TypeUtil$1.visit(TypeUtil.java:31)
at org.apache.parquet.schema.GroupType.accept(GroupType.java:226)
at org.apache.parquet.schema.TypeUtil$1.visit(TypeUtil.java:31)
at org.apache.parquet.schema.GroupType.accept(GroupType.java:226)
at org.apache.parquet.schema.TypeUtil$1.visit(TypeUtil.java:31)
at org.apache.parquet.schema.TypeUtil$1.visit(TypeUtil.java:37)
at org.apache.parquet.schema.MessageType.accept(MessageType.java:55)
at org.apache.parquet.schema.TypeUtil.checkValidWriteSchema(TypeUtil.java:23)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.<init>(ParquetFileWriter.java:228)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetWriter.<init>(ParquetWriter.java:273)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetWriter$Builder.build(ParquetWriter.java:494)
```

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but perhaps `list` in class `Output` should be defined as `Map<String,List<Map<String,Object>>>` instead to take the outermost json object into account?

Comment: @RogerGustavsson: No it won't work as the input list is simple only List of Map.
I tried also by replacing the  List<Map<String, Object>> list with Map<String,List<Map<String,Object>>>  but it did not worked.
Getting error: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: (File); line: 1, column: 12] (through reference chain

Comment: @mazaneicha :  User: 638764 do u have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your `OutPut` type contains the type `Object` as the value type in the `Map`:

```
public class OutPut {
    List<Map<String, Object>> list;
}
```

You're using `ReflectData` to infer an Avro schema for your type by introspecting it. However it can't infer anything useful from the `Object` type.

If you change your definition of `OutPut` to use concrete types, for example:

```
public class OutPut {
    List<Map<String, Double>> list;
}
```

then it should work.

Comment: I knew that if I change it to List<Map<String, Double>> then I will not be interpret th data, as if you forget to see the input data it is of type double, string, long like _t is long and "ts_id id String similarly  mainBearingX is of type double, if it is that simple why on this world I would have posted the question it here. Please understand the question before making it -ve.

Comment: I have fixed this issue and published my content on medium.com  https://medium.com/@rajnishtiwari2010/conversion-of-json-to-parquet-format-using-apache-parquet-in-java-b694a0a7487d